# lookup field update plugin review

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've written a plugin to change or update the value of a lookup field on Merge message.
I tried to debug using profiler but I am not able debug it is asking for download log location which I don't have. So I am asking here for your help.
Since this plugin is registered on Merge message I am using subordinateId for the guid of the child record and I've used fetch to retrieve the attributes.

```html
EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));
foreach (var item in ec.Entities)
                            {
                                item.Attributes["subordinatedId"] = new EntityReference("task", subordinateId);
                                item.Attributes["new_taskissuephase"] = entityTaskIP;
                                service.Update(item);
}
ExecuteMultipleResponse multipleResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

Where did I go wrong in updating the lookup field? Someone please review.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any immediate problem with your code, so we really should get the debug tool working.

It's quite possible it's trying to update the old record (which is probably read only) or that the proper attributes are not being passed through to the plugin. By default only the fields that are changed get passed into the plugin, so it's possible that you will have to perform a lookup before you can update the field with the correct task ID.

Have you installed the plugin profiler? The button will look like this if you have. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc8ez.png

once that's completed, we need to set up your plug in to throw and exception whenever it runs.

Click on the step in question and go "Start Profiling". select exception and press okay.

At this point in time a pop up will come up every time the plugin runs. This is the log file that the plugin registration tool is looking for. If this pop up does not come up, It might mean that there is a problem with the message registration. Merge is a bit of a funny one.

I'd start there, once you have the debug tool working you'll be able to take a look at the variables directly.

Comment: Ok..I will start looking into how to make my profiler work. As a side note as you said, probably it is updating read only. Because I have another plugin that cancels that particular record on the same 'Merge' message. so after that record fields are all read only. But I've ranked the plugins 1 and 2 for updating lookup field and canceling the record respectively. Do you see any potential problem in conjunction with this other plugin? Thank you

Comment: Yeah, I've had issues with plugins that trigger other plugins. Race conditions aren't good, especially when you are using anything that might be async.

If you have multiple steps that have to be performed in a certain order, it's best to consolidate them into one operation. 

Alternatively, you can register the merge step on the "Pre-Operation" pipeline so that it executes the plugin BEFORE changing the record to read only and performing the rest of the steps. This can cause some delay, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I've tried registering 'Pre-Operation' mode but still didn't work. Also I've disabled the other plugin and tried too with no luck.

Comment: Arthur, I cannot download the error file as I am only seeing this error. " we couldn't merge 1 cases. 1 case failed: An error has occurred. Try this action again. If the problem continues, contact.....". How can I proceed in debugging at this stage. Thanks

Comment: If you go to system jobs under settings, can you see that the plugin is executing?

Comment: That's weird... I wonder if it's being called at all. what entity do you have it registered to be triggered on

Comment: It is registered on Incident entity.